# Socket code Python code at the end influences code in the beginning

Tags: python, sockets, ffmpeg, operating-system

So basically i am trying to do the following things : Client sends project file, Server receives Project file, Server generates Video file, Server sends video File, Client receives Video File. Everything works up until sending the Video back. The Thing is when i include my code for sending the Video, not even the Things that worked before work anymore.
The commented code in the code is the code that should send the Video back

Client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
ip = socket.gethostname()
file = "testae.aep"
s.connect((ip, 1234))

f = open(file, "rb")
txt = f.read(1024)
while txt:
    s.send(txt)
    print(f"Sending... {txt}")
    txt = f.read(1024)
f.close()
#f2 = open("final_output.mp4", "wb")
#txt2 = s.recv(1024)
#while txt2:
#    f2.write(txt2)
#    txt2 = s.recv(1024)
#f2.close()
print("received final output")
s.close()
```

Server:

```
import os
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
counter = 0
s.listen(5)
aerpath = "C:/aerender.lnk"
ffmpegpath = '"C:/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"'

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Client Connected")
    print(addr)
    f = open(f"ae_render_file{counter}.aep", "wb")
    txt = c.recv(1024)
    while txt:
        f.write(txt)
        print(f"Receiving... {txt}")
        txt = c.recv(1024)
    print("Out of WHILE")
    f.close()
    print("received file")
    os.system(aerpath + " -project " + f"C:/Users/weilu/PycharmProjects/localAERF/ae_render_file{counter}.aep "
              + '-comp "Comp 1" ' + f"-output C:/Users/weilu/PycharmProjects/localAERF/output/output{counter}")
    os.system(ffmpegpath + " -i " + f"output/output{counter}.avi -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v main "
                                    f"-pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -hide_banner output/outputr{counter}.mp4")
    #f2 = open(f"output/outputr{counter}.mp4","rb")
    #txt2 = f2.read(1024)
    #while txt2:
    #    c.send(txt2)
    #    print("Sending...")
    #    txt2 = f.read(1024)
    #f2.close()
    c.close()
    counter += 1
```

Comment: are you sure there are no errors in the ffmpeg command ran by server? Did you try to execute it by itself?

Comment: os.system isn't blocking. So your server-script does not wait for the ffmpeg progress to finish before sending it back.

Comment: @NikosM. the ffmpeg command also works with the programm, just not sending back the output of ffmpeg

Comment: @MauriceMeyer is there a way to make it block/wait for it to finish, or is there an alternative solution ?

Comment: You need to use subprocess.Popen(...) with [communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)